# Display sesstionStorage string in HTML view Angular 8?

Tags: angular, session, model-view-controller

I simply want to display the data that I stored in the sessionStorage in my angular view.

My sesstionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('username');
```

My dashboard.ts file:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUserSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<div *ngIf = "username">
          <p class="introText"><b>Welkom:</b> {{ username }}
            <button mat-button (click)="clockIn()" class="mat-raised-button mat-primary clockButton">
              Inklokken
            </button>
            <button mat-button type="submit" class="mat-raised-button mat-basic">
              Uitklokken
            </button> <br> 
            <b>Ingelogd: </b>{{dateTime}}
      </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this needs to be a question. You already know how to fetch the value from session storage, so why can't you just store the value when you fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dashboard.ts file:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.username = this.authenticationService.getUsername();
  }
}
```

authentication.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService{
   getUsername():string {
      return sessionStorage.getItem('username');
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  username;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
  }
}
```

and

```
<p class="introText"><b>Welkom:</b> {{ username }}
```